# Как сделать валидацию инпута c типом number Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, input

Не пойму как написать проверку на введенное значение, чтобы нельзя было ввести число <1 и >99
Все что писала до этого не работает

```
<input
              class="qty__input form__input"
              type="number" 
              @input="validateInputData(product.qty)"
              v-model="product.qty">
 
<script>
 methods: {
    validateInputData(qty) {
      // this.$emit("validateInputData")
      if (qty < 1 || qty === "" || qty === 0) {
        qty = 1;
      } 
      else if (qty >= 99) {
        qty = 99;
      } 
      else {
        qty = qty;
      }
    }
</script>
```

подскажите как это сделать на vue.js

Comment: нативные атрибуты инпута  `min` и  `max` - не подходят?

Comment: А по сути - присвоение надо делать не переменной `qty`, а на то, что в `v-model`  передается - `product.qty`

Comment: min и max не срабатывают. Пробовала и product.qty и input.value. Не пойму как до него достучаться

Answer (score 0):

Вот так. Но вообще, правильнее подсвечивать ошибку а не молча менять на валидное значение

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    product: {
      qty: 1
    },
  },
  methods: {
    validateInputData() {
      if (this.product.qty < 1) return this.product.qty = 1;
      if (this.product.qty > 99) this.product.qty = 99;
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input
    v-model="product.qty"
    type="number"
    @input="validateInputData()"
  />
</div>
```